# How to disable routing to <a href="#" > in angular 8?

Tags: angular, routes, href, materialize

I'm using local reference like this

```
<a class="btn-floating btn-large blue" href="#">button</a>
```

But Angular redirects me to some another link localhost:4200/#

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use an `<a>`?

Comment: yeah, I'm sing materializecss modal in angular which goes like this.

https://materializecss.com/modals.html

Comment: How are you integrating it - are you using an Angular library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just call `preventDefault` method of the click event

```html
<a class="btn-floating btn-large blue" href="#" (click)="$event.preventDefault()">
button
</a>
```

or just remove the href attribute

```html
<a class="btn-floating btn-large blue" >
button
</a>
```

you navigate in the page by using `scrollIntoView` method.

```html
<a (click)="skils.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})">Skils </a>
....
<div #skils>...</div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-in-page-scroll)

Comment: is this `(click)="$event.preventDefault()"`working for you

Comment: No, actually I don't want to preventDefault(), I had tried it earlier.
How would you go to a particular section in the same page with `<a href="#skill">skill</a>`

Comment: I have include a way to navigate in the page check the update answer

Answer (score -1):

you can do like this.

```
<a class="btn-floating btn-large blue" href="javascript:">button</a>
```